# Popstate not triggering on Chrome for Android when clicking the back button

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile, pushstate, popstate

Upon clicking the back button in the browser, I would like to prevent the default behaviour of going one page back and instead do an action. I'm using the "popstate" event listener. The following function (I'm using Vue 2) works in all major browsers and even in Firefox for Android, but when I test it in Chrome for Android, it simply goes back one page without popstate being triggered at all.

```
mounted() {
    history.pushState(null, null, <current-url>);
    window.addEventListener("popstate", () => { alert(1) });
}
```

I tried wrapping the popstate event inside the load event and giving it a timeOut of 0, but it still didn't work specifically in Chrome for Android. The version I'm testing on is 93.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chrome popstate not firing on Back Button if no user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339098/chrome-popstate-not-firing-on-back-button-if-no-user-interaction)

Comment: As you write in answer, I flag it as duplcate :)

Answer (score 2):

I did some more research and it seems that Chrome won't let you use popstate if there is no user interaction first. As long as you click on something or scroll down on mobile, popsate will work, otherwise it won't. I tried to simulate user interaction with `click()`, but that didn't work either. It seems Chrome wants genuine user interaction. I also realized this is sort of a duplicate of: [Chrome popstate not firing on Back Button if no user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339098/chrome-popstate-not-firing-on-back-button-if-no-user-interaction)