# Nothing happens when click on browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, single-page-application, back

`popstate` event does not get fired when clicking on the browser back button this is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
        window.history.pushState('forward', null, './#forward');

        $(window).on('popstate', function() {
          alert('Back button was pressed.');
        });
      }
    });
```

When put this code in the console it works but when I put in the file and try to load the page and click on the back button nothing happens. It redirects me to the previous page no alert.
I noticed if do not do anything on the screen then it does not work but if you click on scroll on the screen then the popstate event gets called

Comment: Try using the browser's debugger tool. You can set breaks points, inspect the variable and such to see what's happening.

Comment: its related to this question. It will give more understanding of the senario: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339098/chrome-popstate-not-firing-on-back-button-if-no-user-interaction