# Detecting User Navigation through Session History in a Web Browser

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events, microsoft-edge

I would like to be able to detect when the user navigates through session history using the browsers navigation buttons. When the user logs out, the login page should be the only page that can be selected, the navigation buttons should also default to the login page.
From what I have learned so far, writing an event listener; `window.addEventListener()` for the popstate event should provide this ability.
I have written a handler based on the example shown at: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event)

My environment:
Running Live Server in VS Code, v1.83.0 on Edge Version 117.0.2045.60 (Official build) (64-bit)

While popstate events are triggered when I add history using the `history.pushstate()` methods as shown in the docs and included below, navigating using `<a>` tag and the navigation buttons alone will not trigger popstate events, i.e. when the history methods are commented out.
From what I have read, quote; "The popstate event will be triggered by doing a browser action such as a click on the back or forward button (or calling `history.back()` or `history.forward()` in JavaScript)".

See attached code:

Index page:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!--
        Demonstrate using window.addEventListener() to process popstate events.
        Based on: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event
        Oct 7, 2023.
    -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo using addEventListener to process popstate events.</title>
</head>
<body id="myBody">
   <h3>This is the Index Page</h3>
   <a href="/page1.html">Go to page 1</a>
   <p>Use the navigation buttons to trigger "popstate" events</p>
   
   <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the page I am navigating to, page1.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!--
        Demonstrate using window.addEventListener() to process popstate events.
        Oct 7, 2023.
    -->
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Demo using addEventListener() to process popstate events. Page-1</title>
</head>
<body id="myBody">
    <h3>This is Page-1</h3>
    <p>Use the back navigation button to return to the Index page and trigger a "popstate" event</p>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript, index.js:

```js
window.addEventListener('popstate', (event) => {
  console.log(
    `location: ${document.location}, state: ${JSON.stringify(event.state)}`,
  );
});

// history.pushState({ page: 1 }, "title 1", "?page=1");
// history.pushState({ page: 2 }, "title 2", "?page=2");
// history.replaceState({ page: 3 }, "title 3", "?page=3");
// history.back(); // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=1, state: {"page":1}"
// history.back(); // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html, state: null"
// history.go(2); // Logs "location: http://example.com/example.html?page=3, state: {"page":3}"
```

---

Answer (score 1):

First, `popstate` must be used along with `pushState`. You can refer to [`pushState` doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState):

> This method is asynchronous. Add a listener for the `popstate` event in order to determine when the navigation has completed.

Second, please pay attention that `popstate` is not fired when the page is not interacted with. It's by design in chromium. You can refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339098/chrome-popstate-not-firing-on-back-button-if-no-user-interaction) and this statement in the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/popstate_event#when_popstate_is_sent):

> It's important to first understand that — to combat unwanted pop-ups — browsers may not fire the `popstate` event at all unless the page has been interacted with.

Comment: I was hoping to get an example I could use to base my solution on, your comments are valid and reinforce my knowledge to-date. I have found a resource I am working through that provides more background; (https://www.codeguage.com/courses/js/events-popstate-event). Will post an update once I have finished reading this.

Comment: That's great! You can post your solution as an answer once you finish researching.