# 'popstate' event not firing when clicking back button in Chrome

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, popstate

I have something like a single page web application. To handle a back button click from the user I use the 'popstate' event:

I have something like a single page web application. To handle a back button click from the user I use the 'popstate' event:

In Firefox and Safari, the event works normally - instead of going to the previous page (login page), navigation inside the application occurs.

In Chrome, after the latest updates, the event is **correctly called only once**. If you press the "back" button a second time, the event will not work and the user will be taken to the login window.

Here's my code:

```
function removeBack(){
        history.pushState(null, null, '');
        window.addEventListener('popstate', function () {
console.log('backOneStep0') ;       
            backOneStep(0); // return to the previous application screen
            history.pushState(null, null, '');
        });
    };
```

**Note** - if you click anywhere on the page before the second click, the event will fire a second time.

UPD. Here - [Chrome popstate not firing on Back Button if no user interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57339098/chrome-popstate-not-firing-on-back-button-if-no-user-interaction)

They say that this is how it should be, but until recently everything worked! How then can you make a single-page application if you can’t catch the back button being pressed?

Last version of my code:

```
const state = { page_id: 1, user_id: 5 };

function f1() {
    backOneStep(0);
    history.pushState(state, '', '');           
}

history.pushState(state, '', '');
window.addEventListener('popstate', f1 );


function backOneStep( flg ) {

console.log('backOneStep:',idStatus);
    if ( idStatus == -2 ) {
        return;
    }
    if ( idStatus == -1 ) {
        toStart();
        return;
    }       
    if ( userId < 1 ) return;
    if ( idStatus == 2 ) {
        closeOneTask();
        idStatus = 1;
        return;
    }
    if ( idStatus == 3 ) { // ???
        hideAttachFile();
        idStatus = 2;
        return;
    }
```

and so on... Still work only once in Chrome :(

Comment: What does `backOneStep(0)` do? 

Comment: Hi! It's my own function that returns user to the previous screen of application.

Comment: Every time you call `removeBack`, you are adding an `eventListener`. Try that once, outside of the function. 

Comment: @deEr Thank you for response. Do you mean try adding an eventListener outside of the function?

Comment: Yes i do mean outside of the function. 

Comment: The key detail is that everything works in Firefox, but in Chrome it only works once (if you didn’t touch the page before pressing “back” a second time)

Comment: I cannot replicate that behaviour on my own `popstate` site...

Comment: How often do you call `removeBack()`?

Comment: Once, when the page loads for the first time. It's something like single page application

Comment: I try: Do you interfere at `backOneStep()` with the native `history.pushState()`? 

Comment: Thank you very much for trying to help! I don't touch any 'history.pushState()' in 'backOneStep()' function.

Last version of my code: 

`const state = { page_id: 1, user_id: 5 };
function f1() {
 // backOneStep(0);
 history.pushState(state, '', '');   
}
history.pushState(state, '', '');
window.addEventListener('popstate', f1 );`

Comment: Can you build your whole application on using `history.pushState('','',url)`?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand what you mean :( . 

Maybe I just don't know the right way to make a single page application. 

I have added the latest code and example of `backOneStep( )` function to the post

Comment: I guess you mix `state` and `url`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState 

Comment: I will go think about it until l8er. 